# Ubuntu 16.04 Php 7.0 mysqli failure

Tags: 16.04, server, apache2, mysql, php7

I have commissioned a new Ubuntu 16.04 server with LAMP.  PHP is 7.0.  This line of php now throws a 500 internal error;

```
$result = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pwd', 'dbase');
```

It works fine on my 14.04 PHP 5 server.

I have run

```
php -r 'phpinfo();' | grep -i mysqli
```

The results are

```
mysqli
MysqlI Support => enabled
mysqli.allow_local_infile => On => On
mysqli.allow_persistent => On => On
mysqli.default_host => no value => no value
mysqli.default_port => 3306 => 3306
mysqli.default_pw => no value => no value
mysqli.default_socket => no value => no value
mysqli.default_user => no value => no value
mysqli.max_links => Unlimited => Unlimited
mysqli.max_persistent => Unlimited => Unlimited
mysqli.reconnect => Off => Off
mysqli.rollback_on_cached_plink => Off => Off
API Extensions => mysqli,pdo_mysql
```

When I run `phpinfo()` via a browser, however, I see no sign of mysqli.

Comment: Is `php7.0-mysql` module installed with your php ?

Comment: I do

    php -m | grep -i mysql

and get

    mysqli
    mysqlnd
    pdo_mysql

Comment: use `ctrl + f` in `browser` to find `mysqli` it should be there! Please just try again.

Comment: The only occurrences of 'mysql' in phpinfo() run from browser and using ctrl + f are in the PHP credits section.  This is what is puzzling me.  I can see the modules from the command line but not via the browser and phpinfo().

Comment: Did you install the php7.0-mysql package?  Then restart the web server and the PHP process?

Comment: @Thomas that did the trick.  I installed php7.0-mysql.  It told me I already had the most up-to-date package.  I restarted Apache anyway and all was well.  It may be because I installed Apache before php and never restarted Apache after php install.

Comment: @George, restarting Apache and phpinfo() now shows mysqli.

Comment: nice, glad it worked out.

Answer (score 1):

Followed Thomas' advice. It did the trick. I installed php7.0-mysql. It told me I already had the most up-to-date package. I restarted Apache anyway and all was well.

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

It may be because I installed Apache before php and never restarted Apache after php install.  Restart fixed it.